# Convergence of $\int_{A_n} f$ to $0$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I am looking for a name or a reference in a textbook for the following result in order to quote it.

For any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$-integrable function, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_n} f(x)dx=0,$$
whenever $(A_n:n\geq0)$ is a sequence of measurable set with $\mathcal{L}^1(A_n)\to0$.

It would be clear if we had $1_{A_n}\to0$ a.s. but it not necessarily the case.

Comment: Why do you want to find it in a textbook? It is very easy to proof by dominated convergence...

Answer (score 2):

It's a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem.  The sequence of functions $\{f 1_{A_n}\}$ converges to 0 in measure and is dominated by the integrable function $|f|$.

Comment: Thanks ! I was only aware of the theorem for the almost sure convergence.

Answer (score 1):

The convergence in measure implies the convergence a.e of a subsequence.

Consequently, the 'classical' dominated convergence theorem can be extended to the case where only a convergence in measure is provided.